# Use cell value to determine a range in part of formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am building a counter in Google Sheets that counts how many times a name appears in **a column from Sheet A**:

**Sheet A**

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Ann |
| 4 | Mary |

**Sheet B**

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Name** | **Counter** | **Desired Range of "Sheet A"** |
| 2 | John | 2 | SheetA!A1:A4 |
| 3 | Mary | 1 |  |
| 4 | Ann | 1 |  |

The formula I used in **Sheet B** to count the names in column **A** of **Sheet A** is: `=COUNTIF(SheetA!A1:A4,("*"&A2&"*"))`

The `"&A2&"` is dynamic and gets the value (name) on each respective line of the cell on **Sheet B**.

I want to make the part `SheetA!A1:A4` dynamic too.

Since I am using that same formula in each of the cells in column **B** of Sheet B, I would like that if I edit that one single cell (that states the range of a certain sheet), it would apply to all of the cells using that formula instead of editing each formula.

I am searching for something like this:
`=COUNTIF( C2 ,("*"&A2&"*"))` where **C2** is the range stated on the cell.

Is it possible?

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets.

Comment: @JosWoolley The point is that I'm using formulas....... I don't know if there is much of a difference....

Comment: Use `QUERY()` function like `=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:A,"select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A label A 'Name'")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(C2),"*"&A2&"*")
```

Answer (score 1):

One caveat to the answer above, add the dollar signs around C2 in the function, this way you can drag the formula down, and the reference will always stay in cell C2.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT($C$2),"*"&A2&"*")
```